Android Silent Mode without DND?
I am creating a toggle to switch between Ring-Vibrate-Silent using

audioManager.ringerMode = (audioManager.ringerMode+1)%3

But the problem is, when setting audioManger.ringerMode=0, it is turning on DND mode along with the silent mode. I just want the Silent Mode.
Did anyone figure out a way to implement this?
I followed few solutions given at Enable Silent Mode in android without triggering Do Not Disturb but no luck.
